# Unable to resolve dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement

Tags: fabric8

I've a problem when try deploy a profile on a cluster of fabric8 CR5.

this's a log part on karaf.log

```
2014-09-09 12:33:43,142 | INFO  | o.fabric8.agent) | DeploymentAgent                  | 66 - io.fabric8.fabric-agent - 1.1.0.CR5 | DeploymentAgent updated with {repository.karaf-enterprise=mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/enterprise/2.3.0.redhat-610379/xml/features, optional.mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.10.0=mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.10.0, attribute.parents=feature-camel, feature.insight-log=insight-log, org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultrepositories=file:/opt/fabric8-karaf-1.1.0.CR5/system@snapshots@id=karaf-default,file:/opt/fabric8-karaf-1.1.0.CR5/local-repo@snapshots@id=karaf-local, feature.camel=camel, feature.fabric-jaas=fabric-jaas, attribute.abstract=false, fabric.zookeeper.pid=io.fabric8.agent, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/mortgages/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Mortgages/0.1, feature.camel-blueprint=camel-blueprint, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/varcomty/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Varcomty/0.1, feature.fabric-core=fabric-core, optional.ops4j-base-lang=mvn:org.ops4j.base/ops4j-base-lang/1.4.0, service.pid=io.fabric8.agent, org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public@id=fusepublic, https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public@id=jbosspublic, https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases@id=jbossreleases, https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea@id=jbossearlyaccess, http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=ebrreleases, http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=ebrexternal, http://10.0.0.124:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local@id=pippo, feature.fabric-web=fabric-web, feature.fabric-git-server=fabric-git-server, repository.apache-camel=mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.13.2/xml/features, bundle.mvn:org.talend.esb.job/org.talend.esb.job.api/5.4.1=mvn:org.talend.esb.job/org.talend.esb.job.api/5.4.1, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/equities/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Equities/0.1, resolve.optional.imports=false, repository.fabric8=mvn:io.fabric8/fabric8-karaf/1.1.0.CR5/xml/features, feature.camel-amq=camel-amq, optional.mvn:org.talend.esb.job/org.talend.esb.job.api/5.4.1=mvn:org.talend.esb.job/org.talend.esb.job.api/5.4.1, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/equity_option_warrants/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Equity_Option_Warrants/0.1, feature.karaf=karaf, feature.camel-ftp=camel-ftp, feature.fabric-agent=fabric-agent, feature.jolokia=jolokia, feature.fabric-git=fabric-git, feature.camel-core=camel-core, feature.fabric-camel=fabric-camel, hash=ProfileImpl[id='Anagrafica_Bloomberg', version='1.0']-328b4e0-9859682-9859682-cbe9c83, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/commodities/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Commodities/0.1, repository.karaf-spring=mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/spring/2.3.0.redhat-610379/xml/features, lastrefresh.anagrafica_bloomberg=1410258607347, patch.repositories=https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases, https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea, repository.karaf-standard=mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.0.redhat-610379/xml/features, bundle.mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/vargov_corp_muni/0.1=mvn:anagrafiche_bloomberg/Vargov_Corp_Muni/0.1, bundle.mvn:it.gestielle/anagrafica_bloomberg/1.0=mvn:it.gestielle/Anagrafica_Bloomberg/1.0}
2014-09-09 12:33:44,157 | ERROR | agent-1-thread-1 | DeploymentAgent                  | 66 - io.fabric8.fabric-agent - 1.1.0.CR5 | Unable to update agent
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement [dummy/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=anagrafiche_bloomberg.Commodities; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.1.0,0.1.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve anagrafiche_bloomberg.Commodities/0.1.0: missing requirement [anagrafiche_bloomberg.Commodities/0.1.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.management.counters)"]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:285)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populate(Candidates.java:153)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:148)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentBuilder.resolve(DeploymentBuilder.java:224)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:575)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:301)[66:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.1.0.CR5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_65]
```

this is my local repository

```
http://10.0.0.124:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local@id=pippo
```

set on org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories property where the jar are deploy.

Can someone help me ??
Why the dependencies are not resolve?
Thanks 
Mirko

Comment: I'd check that your repository includes a dependency for `org.apache.cxf.management.counters`. The `dummy` dependency is requiring `anagrafiche_bloomberg.Commodities`, which is in turn requiring the above as an implementation of `osgi.wiring.package`.

Comment: I'm also not at all sure this is a StackOverflow question as such -- strikes me as more about configuration than code, which would put it into the purview of ServerFault.

Comment: thanks, I've added cxf feature and now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dummy/0.0.0.0` is just the entry point -- read the rest of the error where it walks the dependency chain.

You'll see it's requiring `anagrafiche_bloomberg.Commodities`, which is requiring `org.apache.cxf.management.counters`. Be sure to install the CXF package.